# jQuery DataTables - Filter column by exact match

Tags: jquery, regex, search, filter, datatables

Trying to only display exact matches to the search term entered in the search bar.

For instance, I have a search bar that filters by ID#. I want only records that match the exact # entered to display.

So if `123` is entered, I don't want `12345`, `91239`, etc etc to be displayed. Only `123`.

Saw some info about `bRegex` on the FAQ page, but it's not working for me. Any ideas?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Ok solved the problem. However, since the column I am using the exact match on sometimes contains multiple ID #s seperated by commas, I wont be able to use an exact match search.

But for those interested, here is the answer:

```
oTable.fnFilter( "^"+TERM+"$", COLUMN , true); //Term, Column #, RegExp Filter
```

Comment: Hi sir, I'm having the same problem. I was wondering where should I place the code you provided? Because I want to try it if it will solve my problem too. Hope you'll reply.

Comment: Hey, I was able to solve the problem of exact match on multiple ID's separated by commas. Here is a working fiddle for any one else who encounters the problem. 
http://jsfiddle.net/digvijayad/0m94e2v7/

Note: For my case, ids were unique across rows, i.e when searched only 1 row would return.

Answer (score 55):

This will give you exact result for a column.

```
 table.column(i)
 .search("^" + $(this).val() + "$", true, false, true)
 .draw();
```

ie . search( input , regex, smart , caseInsen )

Comment: In my case, I am passing multiple values for search and this solution is not working for me. Can you help me over here?

Comment: Breaks the moment you have a special character in your input, (e. g. "+", "(", "!", etc) which isn't that uncommon. 
Rule Nr. 1: NEVER WORK WITH UNSANITIZED INPUT!

Answer (score 11):

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    $('#example').dataTable( {
        "oSearch": {"bSmart": false}
    } );
} )
```

Try using the bSmart option and setting it to false

**From the documentation**

> "When "bSmart" DataTables will use it's smart filtering methods (to
>   word match at any point in the data), when false this will not be
>   done."

UPDATE

I found this:

```js
oSettings.aoPreSearchCols[ iCol ].sSearch = "^\\s*"+'1'+"\\s*$";
oSettings.aoPreSearchCols[ iCol ].bRegex = false;
oSettings.aoPreSearchCols[ iCol ].bSmart= false;
```

at this link http://www.datatables.net/forums/discussion/4096/filtering-an-exact-match/p1

looks like you can set `bSmart` and `bRegex` per column as well as specifying a manual regex per column.

Comment: Not quite what I am looking for. So basically I have 3 custom search fields I use to filter the table. I only want one of the fields to use an exact search. For the other fields, I want them to still use the smart search.

Comment: Also on a side note, the bSmart basically means if I type in "John Smith", it will find any combination of those words (i.e. "Smith John", "John Jack Smith", etc etc.)

Answer (score 4):

You can use regular expression for exact matching as following:

```
var table = $('#dt').DataTable();

$('#column3_search').on('keyup', function () {
    // Note: column() accepts zero-based index meaning the index of first column is 0, second column is 1 and so on.
    // We use `2` here as we are accessing 3rd column whose index is 2.
    table.column(2)
         .search("^" + this.value + "$", true, false, true)
         .draw();
});
```

The syntax of the `search` function is:

> search(input, regex, smart_search, case_insensitive)

We disable *smart search* in this case because `search` function uses regular expression internally when *smart search* is set to true. Otherwise, this creates conflict between our regular expression and the one that is used by `search` function.

For more information, check out the following documentation from *DataTable*:

[column().search()](https://datatables.net/reference/api/column().search())

Hope it's helpful!

Comment: In my case, I am passing multiple values for search and this solution is not working for me. Can you help me over here?

Comment: Can you explain what exactly you are trying to do?

Comment: in the example given by you - this.value is a single value. Instead of that, I am passing multiple values i.e. (1|2|3) in search function.

Comment: Multiple values are from the different input fields?

Comment: Does this approach work when column value contains `^`, `$` or other regex-reserved characters (like `.`)?

Comment: @izogfif https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32846782/how-to-escape-special-characters-in-regular-expressions. Check this out. You can do that escaping regex reserved characters. That way, you can filter out the values easier.

Answer (score 3):

just set the regex and smart false. and you get the exact result.

```
 $('#yourTableID').DataTable({ 
  search: {
     regex: false,
     smart: false
  }
 })
```

Comment: In my case, I am passing multiple values for search and this solution is not working for me. Can you help me over here?

Answer (score 2):

If you want the exact match from the beginning you can try this code,

```
    var table = $('#myTable').DataTable()
    $('#filterrow > th:nth-child(2) > input').on( 'keyup change', function () {
        table
        .column( $(this).parent().index()+':visible' )
        .search( "^" + this.value, true, false, true )
        .draw();
    } );
```

Comment: $('#filterrow > th:nth-child(2) > input') is a selector

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    tbl = $('#example').dataTable();
    tbl.fnFilter("^" + filter_value + "$");
});
```

Where `filter_value` is the string entered in the filter field.

Comment: Didn't return any results...?

Answer (score 0):

Regex was not a handy solution for me as it require lot of exceptions in the code.
So, my solution was to add in the jquery.datatable.min.js a new option 'exactvalue' with default value false (to avoid compatibility problems)

```
    [...]
p.columns.push({data:n,name:u.sName,searchable:u.bSearchable,exactvalue:u.bExactvalue,orderable:u.bSortable,
    [...]
d.bFilter&&(m("sSearch_"+l,sa.sSearch),m("bRegex_"+l,sa.bRegex),m("bSearchable_"+l,u.bSearchable),m("bExactvalue_"+l,u.bExactvalue));
    [...]
q.models.oColumn={idx:null,aDataSort:null,asSorting:null,bSearchable:null,bExactvalue:null,bSortable:null,bVisible:null
    [...]
q.defaults.column={aDataSort:null,iDataSort:-1,asSorting:["asc","desc"],bSearchable:!0,bExactvalue:false,bSortable:!0,
    [...]
```

This new option will be sent along the other data in the post:

```
   [...]
   columns[5][searchable]: true
   columns[5][exactvalue]: true
   columns[5][orderable]: true
   [...]
```

After that, change the php ssp class to accept the new value. Modify filter function in the ssp changing:

```
            if ( $requestColumn['searchable'] == 'true' ) {
                if ( $requestColumn['exactvalue'] == 'true' ) {
                    $binding = self::bind( $bindings, $str, PDO::PARAM_STR );
                     $columnSearch[] = ($isJoin) ? $column['db']." = ".$binding : "`".$column['db']."` = ".$binding;
                }else{
                    $binding = self::bind( $bindings, '%'.$str.'%', PDO::PARAM_STR );
                     $globalSearch[] = ($isJoin) ? $column['db']." LIKE ".$binding : "`".$column['db']."` LIKE ".$binding;
                }
            }
```

and repeat on the individual column filtering

```
        if ( $requestColumn['searchable'] == 'true' && $str != '' ) {
            if ( $requestColumn['exactvalue'] == 'true' ) {
                $binding = self::bind( $bindings, $str, PDO::PARAM_STR );
                 $columnSearch[] = ($isJoin) ? $column['db']." = ".$binding : "`".$column['db']."` = ".$binding;
            }else{
                $binding = self::bind( $bindings, '%'.$str.'%', PDO::PARAM_STR );
                 $columnSearch[] = ($isJoin) ? $column['db']." LIKE ".$binding : "`".$column['db']."` LIKE ".$binding;
            }
        }
```

Now, in your table columnDefs definition, simply add

```
{'targets': 5, 'exactvalue': true}
```

and your column will be filtered with exact value.

Answer (score -1):

The current versions of Datatables supports using real exact matching on a column basis.

```
table.column(i)
.search($(this).val(), false, false, false)
.draw();
```

The [documentation](https://datatables.net/reference/api/column().search())  explains each flag.

Comment: In my case, I am passing multiple values for search and this solution is not working for me. Can you help me over here?

Comment: This absolutely does not work. Just as with the default behaviour of search, this will match values in the table containing the search term, not just those exactly matching it.

Answer (score -3):

table.column(col_num).search(filter_value + "$", true, true, false).draw();