# Search text in first colum only and highlight

Tags: jquery, datatable

Currently search text is searching on all columns. I just want to search on first column and also want to  highlight the searched text. I red the documentation of datatable but it getting over from my mind. Is there any simple way to get this done. [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yg32o2yh/2/)

```
$(document).ready(function(){    
   var table= $('#example').DataTable({
        paging:false,     
        ordering:false
    });

    $('#search-inp').keyup(function(){
      table.search($(this).val()).draw() ;
})

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is one option in dataTable UI it is search `column` property. if you want serach the first column only means you just put `.column(1)`

```
$('#search-inp').keyup(function(){
       table.columns(1)
       .search($(this).val()).draw() ;
})
```

for hide the default search add the line

```
 $(".dataTables_filter").hide();
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/yg32o2yh/3/)

Note : Doc from https://datatables.net/reference/api/column().search()

Comment: Thanks, Your fiddle is working fine, just need to know Can we hide default search input?

Comment: `$(".dataTables_filter").hide();`

Comment: Thanks once again, I just notice that the it is filtering all the result which match with the search text. How to enable exact match. like if I have "avenger" and "myavenger", If I type "aven" then only first one will display

Comment: I checked this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8609577/jquery-datatables-filter-column-by-exact-match but it seems not working

Comment: You ask lot of questions better than you will raise a question independently. Thanks