# How to escape special characters in regular expressions

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, datatables

For my website I use the [dataTable](https://www.datatables.net/) plugin and to give the user the possibility to filter the results. I implemented some filter, which are dynamically loaded from the results and contains the all different values of each column.

As more than one filter can be combined, I deactived the smart search and had to active the regEx-search instead. All these things are working fine.

**My Problem is:** I have content like "content (another content)", and for those contents containing brackets, the search doesn't work (no result is found).

Is there a possibility to mask the `searchString` before calling:

```js
table.column('myColumn:name').search(searchString, true, false, true).draw();
```

I tried to replace the string with "\)" or something like this, but that doesn't help. If I just delete those special characters the results can't be found either as regEx search needs exact strings.

Can anyone help me please?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> **SOLUTION**

You can add and use a function `escapeRegExp()` that will escape special 
characters as found in [MDN - Regular Expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#Using_special_characters) article:

```js
function escapeRegExp(string){
  return string.replace(/[.*+?^${}()|[\]\\]/g, "\\$&");
}

// ... skipped ...

table.column('myColumn:name').search(escapeRegExp(searchString), true, false, true).draw();
```

> **DEMO**

See [this jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/smsLr48u/) for code and demonstration.