# DataTables column search for exact match

Tags: jquery, datatable

I am using jQuery [DataTables](https://datatables.net/examples/api/regex.html) plugin in my application. I am trying to search for a string that **exactly matches** the data in a column.

I checked the [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8609577/jquery-datatables-filter-column-by-exact-match) and its solution is not working for my case. My search string is a *regular expression* with `|` symbols which might look like `Logged In|Active|Not Active`.

When the search string contains `Active(Logged In|Active)`, records with `Not Active` are also showing up when I use the following search:

```
jQuery("#myTable").DataTable()
                .columns("#status")
                .search("^"+status+"$",true,false)
                .draw();
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
jQuery("#myTable").DataTable()
                .columns("#status")
                .search("(^"+status+"$)",true,false)
                .draw();
```

This worked!

Comment: This by far is the simplest answer I've seen. (And it works.)

Comment: You saved my day bro! Worked like a charm. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try below solution:
1. with smart search off ([reference](https://datatables.net/reference/api/search()))

```
jQuery("#myTable").DataTable()
                .columns("#status")
                .search(status,false)
                .draw();
```

2.with double quotes ([reference](https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/23992/exact-word-search))

```
jQuery("#myTable").DataTable()
                    .columns("#status")
                    .search('"'+status+'"')
                    .draw();
```

Comment: Since we have multiple search words, we should be going for a regEx search. So the above solution would not work

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
 $('#yourTableID').DataTable({ 
  search: {
     regex: false,
     smart: false
  }
 })
```

You can find more information here: https://datatables.net/reference/option/search